# elements in $C^*$ algebra

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

If $x$ is an element of a $C^*$ algebra $A$,Is $exp^x$ an element of $A$?

My thought:  compute the Taylor expansion of $exp^x$,but it is a sum of countable terms.Is sum closed in $A$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's first assume that $A$ is unital. Then let's define, for $x \in A$
\begin{equation}
\exp(x) = \lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{n=0}^{N} x^{n}/n!
\end{equation}
The question is now if this limit converges to anything in our C$^{*}$-algebra. The answer to this question is yes, this can be shown by proving that the sequence
\begin{equation}
a_{N} = \sum_{n=0}^{N} x^{n}/n!
\end{equation}
is Cauchy, which I'll leave as an exercise. (Hint: the norm is submultiplicative.)

Comment: Thanks,Imade a mistake.I thought $\exp^x$ is also in A even if $A$ is non-unital.Besides the polynomial of $x,x^*$,do there exist special elements which lie in $A$ when $A$ is non-unital?If $A$ is non-unital,can we take some function $f$ act on x such $f(x) \in A$?

Comment: I'm not sure how te define $\exp(x)$ if $A$ is non-unital. For example, what would you propose $\exp(0)$ to be? For more general functions, you might want to look into the functional calculus. Any book about C$^{*}$-algebras should treat this at some point.

Comment: I've found the functional calculus for the unital $C^*$ algebras,would you mind recommending some reference books about functional calculus. for non-unital $C^*$ algebras?